# How discard a file change in git

Tags: git

I'm sure that this question has been answered many times, but I couldn't find the answers. The thing is this. 
I have to modified several files and commit those changes to a git repository. But sometimes, I add some unexpected change to a file (add a blank space, cut a chunk of code to realize that I am in the erroneous file, so I paste again that chunk in the previous place and I save the file), and every time git detected that action as file change, so ask me to commit those changes. 
But I can't commit those changes (I have to justified every commit, and I can't type "added blank space" or so). 
How I could tell git to ignore those changes? I don't want to revert the files to a previous state, I want to say to git "this files are Ok, don't commit the false changes, ignore them"

Comment: Sorry, there is no way to tell git to ignore specific changes. You could get rid of those changes (and if they're really just things like blank space then that shouldn't pose a problem). Use `git reset --hard HEAD` to throw away *all* changes, or `git checkout -p` to interactively pick which changes to throw out.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Comment: You'd do well to run ``git diff --check <changed files>`` before staging them, or ``git diff --cached --check`` after you've staged them. It reports whitespace errors. Look for the ``--check`` command line option in ``git help diff``.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't pushed your repo somewhere, add your changes to the index, and then amend your last commit:

```
git add file_with_change
git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is that I just go ahead and make the commit, like `adding blank space`, `formatting` etc. usually with some identifying word like `MINOR`:

```
git commit -m "MINOR formatting"
```

Then I carry on with work, making commits as I go, and then when I am ready push, I do a `git rebase -i` and just squash the `MINOR` (the `MINOR` or something similar in the message helps in quickly picking these commits in the interactive rebase list) commits to the previous commits. Or even group them all together into one piece if that makes sense, and then push the commits.

But to answer your exact question, the way to "discard" change in a file, so that git will track it, but still ignore the changes is to:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file
```

but I DON'T recommend doing that.